# Display a different components in a click of a button (react component class)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick, components

I created two `dropdowns selection`, `input`, and a `button` in my `Addroom component` and I want to display that component in my main page only in a click of the `button` - it will look like a page with a single button.

After the user will finish fill the details (at `Addroom component`) and clicking on the `Create button` I want to display the `titles` with the `values` that the user filled - `Room component`.

In the current situation, everything is just already on the main page..
[image]

- the `Addroom component` with elements for fill out.
- the `Room Component` with the titles that filled with the user details.

And this is what I want it to look like:
[image]

*I hope the explanation is understandable - these are two buttons...*

I have tried different `methods` to display the components separately but none of the methods work properly and just made a lot of mess that I couldn't understand in the code.
I tried things like `boolean values` and tried to create a button based on the specific condition, and also methods that based on the state value that contact `operators` with `functions` to update the `state values` based on the unique identifiers.

Is there a simple way to do this without ruin the algorithms that work?
I could really use a hand..
Thank you! and particularly thanks for your patience..

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './App.css';
import Addroom from './components/Addroom.js'
import Room from './components/Room.js'

export default class App extends Component {

  state={
    
    roomsList:[{room:''}],
    roomTypeSelection:[{roomType:''}],
    colorTypeSelection:[{colorType:''}],
    isActive: false
}

handleShow = () => {
  this.setState({isActive: true});
};

handleHide = () => {
  this.setState({isActive: false});
};

create=(r)=> {
  this.setState({roomsList:[...this.state.roomsList,{room:r}]})
} 

getRoomTypeSelection=(rt)=> {
  this.setState({roomTypeSelection:[...this.state.roomTypeSelection,{roomType:rt}]})
} 

getColorTypeSelection=(ct)=> {
  this.setState({colorTypeSelection:[...this.state.colorTypeSelection,{colorType:ct}]})
} 

  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
        
        <h1>My Smart House</h1>

{this.state.roomsList.map((element)=>{
         return <Room r={element.room} rt={element.roomType} ct={element.colorType}/>
       })}

      <Addroom add={this.create}  addRoomType={this.getRoomTypeSelection} addColorType={this.getColorTypeSelection}/>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Addroom.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


export default class Addroom extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            backgroundColor:'white',
            room:'',
            roomNameInputColor:'white',
            roomTypes:["kitchen", "bathroom", "bedroom"],
            roomSelected: [''],
            roomSel:'',
            colorTypes:['red', 'green', 'blue', 'teal'],
            colorSelected:[''],
            colorSel:'',
    };   
        }

        addRoomName = (e) => {
            const room = e.target.value;
          
            let roomNameInputColor = 'white';
            if (e.target.value.length >= 5) {
              roomNameInputColor = 'green';
            } else {
              roomNameInputColor = 'red';
            }
          
            this.setState({ room, addRoomName: room, roomNameInputColor });
          }


    createRoom=()=> {
        this.props.add(this.state.room);
    }

    createRoomType=()=> {
        this.props.addRoomType(this.state.roomSelected);
    }

    createColorType=()=> {
        this.props.addColorType(this.state.colorSelected);
    }


    setCategory = (roomSel) => {
        this.setState({roomSelected : roomSel});
    };

    setColorCategory = (colorSel) => {
        this.setState({colorSelected : colorSel});
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            {/* //Select Room Type */}
            <select onChange={(e) => this.setCategory(e.target.value)}>{this.state.roomTypes.map((type) =>
            <option value={type}>{type}</option>
               )}</select><br/>

            {/* //Select Room Color */}
            <select onChange={(e) => this.setColorCategory(e.target.value)}>{this.state.colorTypes.map((type) =>
            <option value={type}>{type}</option>
               )}
      
            </select><br/>

            <input onChange={this.addRoomName} style={{backgroundColor:this.state.roomNameInputColor}} placeholder='Name Your Room'/><br/>
 
            <button onClick={() => {this.createRoom(); this.createRoomType(); this.createColorType();}}>Create</button>   
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Room.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Room extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Room1: {this.props.r} </h3>
                <h3>Room Type1: {this.props.rt}</h3>
                <h3>Room Color1: {this.props.ct}</h3>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to show the Addroom dropdowns and input when the user has clicked the Create button once, after which they can add a room. For that you can use a state to toggle what to display.

Ive made a quick [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-wilbur-kkibc?file=/src/App.js), please see if that works.

Note: dont forget to add a key when using `map()`, like this:

```js
<select>
    {items.map((value, key) => (
       <option key={key} value={value}>{value}</div>
    ))}
</select>
```

Edit: improved the sandbox code

Comment: Great! You cleaned and rearrange the code for me a bit, now I can read more easily.. The role of the unique key keep the values in the variables?
Really exciting, Thank you so much

Comment: Keeping things clean and simple :) Learn more about the `key` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I will, Thanks again (: